Limit of multivariable function at infinity
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and let $S^{d-1}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose that $f(x)\geq 0 $ for all $x$ and that for every unit vector $u\in S^{d-1}$, we have
$$\lim_{\Vert x\Vert\to\infty} f(\Vert x\Vert u) = 0.$$
Can we conclude that the limit of the function as $\Vert x\Vert \to \infty$ exists and is zero, that is,
$$\lim_{\Vert x\Vert\to\infty} f(x) = 0.$$
My initial guess is the following since $S^{d-1}$ is compact, the family of functions
$$\{f(\Vert x\Vert u)| u\in S^{d-1}\}$$
is uniformly continuous on the sphere $S^{d-1}$. Hence, the behaviour of $f(x)$ as $\Vert x\Vert\to\infty$ can be controlled uniformly over all directions, which shows that
$$\lim_{\Vert x\Vert\to\infty} f(x) = 0.$$
Is this correct? Any help would be appreciated!

For linear paths away from the origin, the 2 expressions are identical.  You would need to check a nonlinear path for the 2 expressions to be different, perhaps some kind of spiral.  This suggests for 2-d a form in polar coordinates could be useful.

Counter-example in two variables
Consider a narrow white band between two hyperbolas, both asymptotic to coordinate axes, e.g  satisfying $ 1/2< |xy|<1.5$.
Set $f$ identically equal to zero on the blue region outside the band, and set $f$ equal to 1 along a third such  hyperbola that lies within that band, e.g. on $|xy|=1$.
(You can make $f$ continuous by expressing it as a composition of two well-behaved functions, $f=T\circ g$  where $g(x,y)=|x y|-1$ and the outer function $T(g)$ is a non-negative triangular pulse that rises and falls   in the interval $.5<g<1.5$ and peaks at $T(1)=1$ ).
Each extended ray from the origin eventually enters the blue zone where $f$ is zero, so radial limits are always zero.  However, the exterior of every large disk centered at the origin contains points where $f$ is large, so $f$ does not tend to zero at infinity.


Thanks a lot for your reply! Are there any conditions that you can impose such that the limit exists and is equal to zero. For example, what if for every $u$, $f(u\Vert x\Vert)$ can be bounded by a strictly decreasing function?

A decreasing majorant always exists, even in the case of this counter-example. For each $u$, as a function of $r=|x|$, by construction the expression $M(r)= sup{ f(u |x|):|x|\geq r}$ is decreasing in $r$ and  by construction it dominates $f(r)$.
